# Unity FBX not opening in Blender

Tags: import, unity, .fbx

So I'm trying to open some of the Standard Asset FBX's in Blender like so:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/Zigbl]

Double click on SkyCarBody and get this in Blender:

[image]

FBX settings in Blender:

[image]

Completely blank project. Any ideas?

Blender v2.78 
Unity v5.5.0f3 
Win10 x64 Pro 
Nvidia 378.49

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you cannot open FBX directly in Blender just by double clicking from with the Unity Editor, you must use the import function (File -> Import -> FBX). I was able to open the model:

[image]